# What is the best way to handle null situations in Kotlin when extending a Java class?

Tags: kotlin

I'm really stuck with situation when something can be null in Kotlin. When a value cannot be null - it is clear. But how to handle situation when something can be null by default. Take a look at this example:

```
abstract class MapActivity: AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    lateinit var map: GoogleMap

    fun initializeMap() {
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {
        this.map = map //error here
    }
}
```

So I should handle that situation this way:

```
override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {
        if (map != null) 
            this.map = map
    }
```

But what if map is **null**. What should I do in this case? I've faced this problem while using java.

Ok, in java, if map is null, we will get NPE.

And for me NPE is better than nothing. The program crashes and this is a signal for me, that something is wrong and I should fix it. In this way, I can't even trace my problem and why it is happen. 
Yeah, we can write something like:

```
override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {
    if (map != null) {
        this.map = map
    } else {
        Log.d("Activity","MapIsNull")
    }    
}
```

and there is some meaning in this code, yes. 
But there is still some hesitation in me head about the whole null safety thing.
Safe calls for example is weird thing which produces null and (In my opinion) heisenbugs or bugs that are hard to catch.

Can someone explain to me what is going on here, and what are the best practices to use null-safety.

*I'm pretty sure that this thing is useful, because I'm not as smart as guys in JB*

Comment: Why wait for the program to crash when the compiler tells you that it will (very likely) crash at some point here?

Comment: It forces me to fix the problem. And indicate where the problem is(stacktrace). Here, I should write some system which would notify me about nulls.

Comment: If map should not be null, then the type should be GoogleMap, not GoogleMap?. Why do you accept a nullable type as argument if it's not supposed to be null.

Comment: What? I received map: GoogleMap? as the argument of override method. I can't change its nullability

Comment: Yes, you can. See yole's answer.

Comment: the name of the question is very vague. @alexeypolusov care to rename?

Comment: how do you want me to rename it?

Comment: I mean a "what-is-the-purpose" question is not very clear and does not help others to find the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of [OnMapReadyCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback) says explicitly that it "provides a non-null instance of GoogleMap". Consequently, the parameter type of your `onMapReady` method should use a non-null type.

Note that, when you implement a Java interface in Kotlin, you have a choice of whether to declare the parameters of the implementing method as nullable or non-null. The IDE marks them as nullable because it's the safe default, but you can change them to non-null if that's what you need.

Comment: Yeah it's nice when it's documented, otherwise I find myself trawling through the code to check if it's actually guarding against `null` input / never returning `null` to ensure it's safe to make my kotlin params/return types non-null. It's worth it though - just makes me like Java a little less each time :)

Answer (score -1):

About dealing with nulls: let's imagine that you need to have a method `fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?)` which would set a class property `map`.

You have two *design* options to choose between:

1) Your app will not work if `map` is `null`

```
class A {
    lateinit var map: GoogleMap  // never ever `null`

    fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {
        map = map!!  // throws
    }

    fun onMapReady2(map: GoogleMap?) {
        map = map ?: throw Exception("in case you care for the exception")
    }
}
```

2) `Null` has special meaning for you and is ok to have:

```
class A {
    var map: GoogleMap? = null  // map is not ready yet

    fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {
        map = map
    }
}
```

Of course, if your case is case (1) and you can control the API, then you should never have a nullable receiver `map: GoogleMap?` because it confuses the user of the class.

Answer (score -1):

I see two separate questions:
1. Null handling
2. Kotlin specific syntax for null handling

First is not a kotlin specific problem. It depends, and @voddan pretty much explained available strategies.

Regarding syntax.
If you interested only in non-null values, use let()

```
override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {
        map?.let { m ->
            // do your staff 
            // 'm' now is definitely not null
        }
    }
```

If you want to know when it is null, use usual if-else block

```
override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {
    if (map != null) {
        this.map = map
    } else {
        Log.d("Activity","MapIsNull")
    }
```

Sidenotes:
1] @Cedric have [nice post](http://beust.com/weblog/2015/10/30/exploring-the-kotlin-standard-library/) about kotlin's let() and friends
2] check out [@yole's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38022508/4594990). when overriding fun in IDEA arguments can be marked as '?', but in fact they aren't.

Comment: Thanks. According to your first link:  // This whole block will not be executed if "config" is null. What If I have some complicated business logic and when I got my "config" null, I would have some bags which are (IMHO) hard to trace. How should I handle that kind of thing?  This is what I'm talking about in my post.